# Storing a string in array to use it later

Tags: c

I want to store a bunch of strings, but I'm having trouble on how to store them. And after that I want to print them but later on in the program, not after I input them.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int total_people, i;
    char name[total_people][20];

    scanf("%d", &total_people);

    for(i = 0; i < total_people; i++) {

        scanf("%[^\n]", name[i][0]);

    }

    for(i = 0; i < total_people; i++) {

        printf("%s", name[i][0]);

    }


return 0;
}
```

I tried inputting `3` and I got a runtime error.

Comment: There are a lot of things wrong with this code. For starters, what is the value of `total_people` when you attempt to create `name`? Also, when you're getting a runtime-error, include it. Maybe use it to debug the program yourself a little bit first...

Comment: that is the problem though the runtime error is because of the question, `total_people` is to define how many time my `for` loops 'loops'. if i input 3 for `total_people` it will loop 3 times and will ask for 3 names.

Comment: Your program will run sequentially. You declare the array to be of size `total_people`, before you actually assign any value to it.

Comment: can i fix that by just moving the `char name[total_people][20];` after my `scanf("%d", &total_people);`, it will have a value by then right?

Comment: Of course. This enables the user to overflow the stack, so you might want to check for that.

Comment: Okay, will do, thank you for the advice for tune-fining my program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`name[i][0]` is the first *character* of the array `name[i]`. You need a *pointer* to that first character, which you can get with the address-operator `&` as in `&name[i][0]`.

Or since array naturally decays to pointers to their first element, just `name[i]`.